# Getting relationships from all node's in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, match, relationships

I am trying to query using Neo4j.
I would like to print result of obtaining information while AUTO-COMPLETE is ON in Neo4j.
For example, suppose query that creating 3 nodes as shown below.

```
create (david:Person {name: 'david'}), (mike:Person {name: 'mike'}), (book:Book {title:'book'}), (david)-[:KNOWS]->(mike), (david)-[:WRITE]->(book), (mike)-[:WRITE]->(book)
```

Here are 2 images:

- Auto-complete on

  [image]
- Auto-complete off

  [image]

Figure is shown after query, and I would like to obtain all relating node’s relationships based on starting node ('book' node).
I used this query as shown below.

```
match (book:Book)-[r]-(person) return book, r, person
```

Whether AUTO-COMPLETE is ON or OFF, I expect to obtain all node’s relationships including “David knows Mike”, but system says otherwise.

I studied a lot of Syntax structure at neo4j website, and somehow it is very difficult for me.  So, I upload this post to acquire assistance for you.

Comment: neo4j website is https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replicate Neo4j browser auto-complete function in a cypher statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029276/replicate-neo4j-browser-auto-complete-function-in-a-cypher-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to InverseFalcon, this is my query that works.

```
MATCH p = (book:Book)-[r]-(person:Person) 
UNWIND nodes(p) as allnodes WITH COLLECT(ID(allnodes)) AS ALLID 
MATCH (a)-[r2]-(b) 
WHERE ID(a) IN ALLID AND ID(b) IN ALLID 
WITH DISTINCT r2 
RETURN startNode(r2), r2, endNode(r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return all the data that you need yourself explicitly. It would be bad for Neo4j to automatically return all the relationships for a super node with thousands of relationships for example, as it would mean lots of I/O, possibly for nothing.

```
MATCH (book:Book)-[r]-(person)-[r2]-()
RETURN book, r, person, collect(r2) AS r2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, this is not the answer that I am looking for.  The answer that InverseFalcon provided is the one that I am looking for, but I appreciate your support.