# Return all nodes and relations among nodes in path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First time asking on SO and a newby of cypher and neo4j.

I need to get all the nodes, and all their relationships, that compose the lineage of a particular node; to display them in a directed graph I need a list of `nodes` and a list of the relationships (`links`).
This is my dummy [set of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFkC1.png), and this is what I want to get (nodes plus links): [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUTzx.png)

This is what I came up after hours of research and attempts:

```
MATCH lineage = (n:Sample {name:"P"})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(parent:Sample)
MATCH (parent)-[r_out]->(child)-[r_in]->(parent)
WHERE parent IN nodes(lineage) OR child IN nodes(lineage) 
RETURN
collect(DISTINCT parent) AS nodes,
collect({ source: parent.name, rel: type(r_out), target: child.name }) AS links_out,
collect({ source: child.name, rel: type(r_in), target: parent.name }) AS links_in;
```

(I created two different list of relationships so i can distinguish the source and target.)

However this does not return n in the list of nodes and actually multiplicates the links, as I guess returns all the possible paths between `n` and all the other nodes.

I could not figure out a solution and I am also convinced it should be a much more elegant query...

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what I was looking for!

```
MATCH lineage = (child:Sample {name:"P"})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(parent:Sample)
MATCH (n:Sample)-[r_out]->(m:Sample)-[r_in]->(n:Sample)
   WHERE n IN nodes(lineage) AND m IN nodes(lineage)
RETURN
   child + collect(DISTINCT parent) AS nodes,
   collect(DISTINCT {source: n.name, rel: type(r_out), target: m.name}) +
   collect(DISTINCT {source: m.name, rel: type(r_in), target: n.name}) AS links
```

The plus sign merges the results in a single array, and so now I have in a single query my two arrays of `nodes` and `links`! :)

Comment: Although what I don't understand is why if I target a node that does not have parent (so no outcoming `CHILD_OF` relationship) I don't get that node, as the only element, in the `nodes` array?
Even if it is not part of the `lineage` path (as the path in this case would not actually exist), isn't the node `child` defined anyway having property `name = P`?

Answer (score 0):

*i THINK i get your question  and in case i do ... (otherwise my apologies )*

Getting the nodes and getting the unique relations between all the nodes that came back is a two step process.   you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029276/replicate-neo4j-browser-auto-complete-function-in-a-cypher-statement/31033239#31033239)

Basically the first request gets you the nodes and then you query for all relationships where either side of the relationship is a node with one of the node ids you got back in the first query

```
match a-[r]-b where id(a) in [1,2...] and id(b) in [1,2,3...] return r
```

*note that the array of integers is the same unique list of node ids from the first query.*